# Java with RWeka package

Tags: javascript, java, macos, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have mac El Capitan, 10.11.5, I used  RWeka package, it downloaded correctly and initialized with any error, but when I apply

```
J48(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

I have this error

```
Error in .jnew("weka/core/Attribute", attname[i], .jcast(levels, "java/util/List")) : 
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: weka/core/Attribute : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I used java version with these  details,

```
52F85:~ kameljabreen$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I also tried installing java JDK version 1.8. Now I used java 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

The `RWeka` package depends on the `rJava` package for R-to-Java communication, which includes and uses its own Java 1.6 runtime. To make things worse, the behavior of the `rJava` package is platform dependent - it uses "built-in" Java on some platforms (Mac OS?) and "system" Java on others.

Comment: yes, Java 1.6 runtime already downloaded from Apple web site and also rJava.

Comment: As the `UnsupportedClassVersionException` demonstrates, you cannot run `RWeka` with Java 1.6. You need to replace it with Java 1.7 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but for mac SE 1.6 is necessary and java jre also, our computer cenetr in Aix marseille university (HGerard Henry) solve this problem as describe in [this link](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/support/doku.php?id=rweka).